# Getting GPS data from Twilio Photo

Tags: twilio, sms

I'm building a app that allows users to text in there photos to a twilio phone number which stores the photo on an AWS server.

However it appears the end photo is modified both in resolution and redacted exif data.

Does anyone know is this something Twilio is doing and can hopefully be switched off or is this happening during transit somehow?

I've tested from multiple phone models / os's and the results always seem the same which makes me think it twilio.

Maybe there is a better way to extract GPS data from a texted photo???

Comment: Friend, see https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133427-Does-Twilio-do-anything-with-the-metadata-passed-with-digital-pictures- for specifics on metadata and digital pictures. What framework/system/method of access are you using? Could you show some code?

Comment: Well that's a bummer. I'm using PHP to read the metadata, but the GPS property doesn't exist so I'm not sure the code is actually relevant.

Comment: out of curiosity, is it possible the GPS metadata is being lost somewhere between the initial handling/request from Twilio and the image being saved on this external server? Somewhere within your app or perhaps even by the AWS server itself as an automated safety mechanism? Many smartphones disable GPS (geolocation) by default and I'm certain many users do so manually. If this is the case you might be able to grab and store it at the *first* point of contact (initial communication from Twilio to your script)

Comment: @john unfortunately it seems to be the carrier that is removing the data.